# Include page dynamically

Tags: apex, visualforce

I have the following code, and I would like to render as PDF:

```
<apex:page controller="MyController">
    <apex:repeat value="{!pagesToShow}" var="page">     
            <apex:include pageName="{!page}" />
    </apex:repeat>
</apex:page>
```

templatesToShow is a list in the controller that holds VF pages.

This doesn't works because apex:include is looking the **page** variable in the controller. But It's not here because it's within the repeat scope.

Any advice to get dynamic page showing?

Comment: Are you trying to show all pages or a single page ? I'm not entirely sure I understand what you're trying to do.

Comment: It would be worth updating your question to mention that you are getting a compilation error saying "**Unknown property 'MyController.page**" on the `apex:include` line

Comment: What I need is generate a PDF which have several sections. Each section can have different design and templating depending on settings.

Comment: possible duplicate of [this question](http://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/15622/include-component-seems-to-be-having-issues-with-merge-field-syntax-inside-of-a): "_apex:include resolves its reference before any other element on a page_"

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can (in a limited fashion) do dynamic includes. The trick is to use the `$Page` global like this:

```
<apex:page>
    <apex:include pageName="{!$Page[$CurrentPage.parameters.include1]}" />
</apex:page>
```

Then direct people to the URL:

**`/apex/DynamicInclude?include1=ThePage`**

Is this something you can build upon?

Comment: I can give it a shot, but a quick thought is that I still need iterate through a list because I can receive a different template (page) for each section, and I can have n sections.